# delegate called on leaving the foucus on textbox

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

textFieldShouldEndEditing is calling only when leaving the focus  from first text field and focus the second text field.. here i want to call the delegate when  i click outside the text box rather than focus the other text box.

Answer (score 0):

1. daclare an instance to UITextField: UITextField *currentTextField;
2. in textfieldDidBeginEditting say currentTextField = textField;
3. place a custom button without image and title all over the screen and give it the action below:

Now your delegate will get called when you tap wherever on the screen (excluding other controls).

```
-(IBAction)hideCurrentKeyboard{
        [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: Without adding a button cant we do this? i want it when i click in empty place in view rather than on button

Comment: You add just an "invisible" button, what's the problem? if you dont wanna add a button, you will have to implement touches delegate, read the touch location and check if the location do not match the bounds of your textfield, and this will be much longer to implement than adding a button